# Flask not rendering data

Tags: python, flask

I have been able to establish a connection to my database using postgreSQL adapter psycopg2, I am able to print the data in the console, but whenever I go to the html page, it doesn't show.

I have looked at the HTML page and my function, but I just cant see where the problem is

app.py:

```
@app.route('/id', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def showIds():

    conn = connectToDB()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute("SELECT id FROM person")
    except:
        print("Error executing SELECT")

    results = cur.fetchall()
    print(results)

    return render_template("id.html", id=results)
```

id.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% for id in results %}
  <li>
      {{ id }}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

I was just expecting a list of the ids in the database, but I can only print it to console.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning your results to "id". Change to this

```
{% for result in id %}
  <li>
      {{ result }}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Haha been staring at this for too long! You are a life saver. Much appreciated!